# Change Default Email Recipient for WooCommerce Emails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do you change the default email address that WooCommerce emails are sent to?

[image]

Currently it's defaulting to the email address that WooCommerce was originally installed with, but the site and shop admin has since changed. I know if I enter an email address into that Recipients field, it'll override the default one, but I'd like to change the default one so I don't have to do that. I've looked in every spot I could find on Wordpress and WooCommerce but I've already updated the email addresses everywhere to the current admin address and it didn't affect the default recipient.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I changed the mail address of the admin user of Wordpress which was then reflected here in "defaults to".